# Couldn't find a Play 2.2 app distribution after 'sbt dist'

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I want to create a distribution of a play app on a Jenkins build server.

I had the impression that this can be done via sbt only and that an installation of play itself is not needed. The reference to play is implemented like this in the plugins.sbt file of my project:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

Now when i enter sbt and run "dist" i would expect that the distribution artifact is stored under the dist folder. But nothing is stored under the dist folder. I do not get an error message. The build completes "successfully".

What do i have to do to get this to work in sbt?

Thanks!

--Edited--:

Looking for the .zip file in an dist folder was just my error, dont know how i came up with it.
But it still doesnt work:
Somehow the distribution, which i can find in target/overview looks differently than how it looked before. 
Before the myApp.zip artifact had an internal structure like this:

```
lib
start
```

now it contains these folders:

```
bin
conf
lib
share
```

plus a copy of itself, so myApp.zip also contains a copy of myApp.zip (kind of a file recursion :)

Basically i think my sbt setup must have an error so i will post it here:

build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```

Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform.scalariformSettings

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "myApp"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val cmd = "git rev-parse HEAD"
  val sha1 = Process(cmd).lines.head    
  IO.write(file("conf/version.conf"), s"""sha1="$sha1"""")

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3",            
    "org.tmatesoft.svnkit" % "svnkit" % "1.7.11",
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-email" % "1.3.1",
    "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth" % "0.11.0",
    "com.unboundid" % "unboundid-ldapsdk" % "2.3.1",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",     
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.0-RC1",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.170"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
   // resolvers += "svnkit repo" at     "http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/"
  )//.settings(scalariformSettings:_*)

}
```

plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn   
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.jamesward" %% "play-auto-refresh" % "0.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.2.1")
```

Is there an error in my build setup that makes the dist task misbehave?

Comment: What docs indicate that the artifact goes into the `dist` dir?

Comment: I could have sworn it was this page: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/ProductionDist but apparently the docs are correct!

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the docs for the corresponding version of Play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dist artifact goes into the `target/universal` directory.

Comment: found it there, thanks! the dist tasks still behaves strangely, i have updated the question.

Comment: Play 2.2 changed from a custom dist generator to the sbt native packager.  So the new format of the zip is due to Play 2.2.

Comment: To sum it up: The stumbling block for me was that with play 2.2 the name of the distribution directory changed to target/universal and that the name of the start file changed from 'start' to <project-name>.